# Why does $T(x)=2x$ keep angles but is not an isometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, operator-theory, orthogonality, isometry

I would like to know why a defined operator $T$ on $V$, as following: $T(\alpha)=2\alpha$ preserves angles but is not an isometry?

Comment: Because it multiplies lengths by $2$?

Comment: and why does it preserve angles?

Comment: Ummm.... what is $V$?

Comment: A finite dimensional vector space

Comment: Suppose $V= \mathbb{R}^n$. Using the standard scalar product, you know that $v \cdot w /(\Vert v \Vert \Vert w \Vert) = \cos (\alpha) $. Then $T(v) \cdot T(w) /(\Vert T(v) \Vert \Vert T(w) \Vert) = (4 v \cdot w)/(4 \Vert v \Vert \Vert w \Vert) = v \cdot w /(\Vert v \Vert \Vert w \Vert) = \cos (\alpha) $. What about if $V$ is not finite? Or you change the scalar product?

Comment: What is the *definition* of an isometry?  What kind of object is $V$?  Please edit your question to add some details and context, lest it be closed (and, ultimately, deleted).

Answer (score 2):

Well I assume by the tags you used that $V$ is supposed to be an inner product space (otherwise we can't really talk about angles). Then $$\frac{\langle Tx, Ty \rangle}{\|Tx\| \|Ty\|} = \frac{\langle 2x, 2y \rangle}{\|2x\| \|2y\|} = \frac{\langle x, y \rangle}{\|x\| \|y\|}$$ where $\| \cdot\|$ is the norm induced by the inner product. Now that is the definition of the cosine of the angle between $Tx$ and $Ty$ on the left and the cosine of the angle between $x$ and $y$ on the right. It is not an isometry because lengths are not preserved (as has been pointed out).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It has help me understanding everything,Yes, it is an inner product vector space, I forgot to put the complete hyothesis

Comment: (1) You may be interested to know  that the command `\|` produces a double vertical bar, which is the usual notation for a norm.  (2) In your first sentence, you express confusion about the setting of the question.  In the future, it might be more helpful to use the comment system to seek clarification from the asker before answering.  This particular question has already been downvoted and has accumulated several close votes, likely for lack of clarity.  Rather than answering such questions immediately, it is preferable to help the asker improve the question.